# change events stop working when a new change event is added to a different element in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am programmatically generating some HTML, and trying to add a listener for a change event the elements.
This works fine for the first object, but as soon as I add the second object the first one stops firing the event. 
In the code example below you'll see the updateLabel function only fires for the last object created. I need it to fire for all of the objects.
I have tried with .onchange, and with an event listener, but get the same results. 
Any help much appreciated.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <!--this is where all the generated HTML goes -->
        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
        mainDomElement = document.querySelector("#main");

        for (var count = 0; count < 4; count++)
        {
            var labelId = 'Label' + count;
            newHTML = '<input class="accordionLabel" type="text" id="' + labelId + '" value="' + labelId + '"/>'
            currentHTML = mainDomElement.innerHTML
            mainDomElement.innerHTML = newHTML + currentHTML

            labelDomObj = document.querySelector('#' + labelId);
            //labelDomObj.addEventListener("change", updateLabel);
            labelDomObj.onchange = function(event){updateLabel(event)}
        }

        function updateLabel(event)
        {
            alert(event.target.value);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: It sounds to me like this might be an issue of not being able to apply handlers to dynamically-created elements. Can you try attaching the handler to an element that is available on load (such as `document`), and using event delegation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be best to take a different approach when creating and adding DOM elements. Try this.

```
for (var count = 0; count < 4; count++)
{
    var labelId = 'Label' + count,
        newHTML = document.createElement('input');

     newHTML.type = 'text';
     newHTML.value = labelId;
     newHTML.id = labelId;
     newHTML.addEventListener('onchange', updateLabel, false);
     mainDomElement.appendChild(newHTML);
}
```

**your code explanation**

```
// this takes the main DOM element and stores a copy of it in the variable.
currentHTML = mainDomElement.innerHTML

/*
This is taking the innerHTML property of the main DOM element. It is then 
trying to concatenate the newly created DOM to that stored in the mainDomElement 
variable. I don’t think this is what you want.
*/
mainDomElement.innerHTML = newHTML + currentHTML

// this is trying to select an element from the DOM that does not exist yet.
labelDomObj = document.querySelector('#' + labelId);

// This is trying to add an event listener to an element that does not exist.
labelDomObj.onchange = function(event){updateLabel(event)}
```

You are also missing sim icons from your variable declarations.

Comment: One note for future users, it should be...
      newHTML.addEventListener('change', updateLabel, false);
not 'onChange'

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with closures, where initializing `var count = 0` within the for loop ultimately results in only the last value getting bound to the event handler.

I believe moving the initialization outside of the loop will fix your issue. Also, ES6 introduced the `let` keyword that scopes the variable in the way you are expecting:

```
for (let count = 0; count < 4; count++) { }
```

See [this excellent introduction to javascript closures](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/README.md#you-dont-know-js-scope--closures) for more information.

Comment: Count is also used to produce the labels values which are correctly numbered, so i don't think this is the issue. (My production code doesn't even use a for loop, new elements are added based on user interactions).
I have tried what you suggest anyway and get exactly the same results as before.